# Cant bring an overlay menu to front of html

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am building a wordpress site and I am trying to make an overlay visible. (So I press the menu button and a full screen menu will appear.)

I cannot see the overlay when I press the button, the javascript function is being called but and the overlay goes full screen I just cannot see it.

I have tried z-index: 1

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="color: green" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>  
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer; color: green" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: When I click your 'open' button, it brings out the nav menu then retracts it when i X it. I'm confused on what the problem is.

Comment: It works in this minimal portal but in my website it is hidden behind everything. I want to know how to bring it to the front

Comment: Have you tried giving other elements a negative z-index? It's hard to say what's happening here since we can't replicate the issue